# cakephp acl admin redirect problem

Tags: cakephp, redirect, acl

I currently have a form where you put in two variables and on submit it redirects to a url like this:

```
http://example.com/deal_user_coupons/check_qr/$var1/4var2
```

but when logged in as admin it goes to:

```
http://example.com/albuquerque/admin/deal_user_coupons/check_qr/$var1/$var2
```

Which makes it show a 404 page.

I was wondering how to get rid of the admin directory slash. I tried looking in the documentation and at a few acl tutorials but nothing came close.

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect form on the exact page you need  using url option.

```
$this->Form->create('Shutk',array('url'=>array('controller'=>'my_controller',
                                  'action'=>'my_action',
                                  'admin'=>false)
                                  )
                   );
```

don't forget to use  in url array. this will remove admin prefix from action attribute of the form.

```
'admin'=>false
```

Comment: This is actually exactly what I have now and it does nothing.